# OS X Application Signing

Tags: macos

To Sign an app built for OS X (so that users with gatekeeper or whatever it's called to use them without a popup do I need to be part of the Mac Dev program? Can I use my iOS program certs?

If I choose not to sign people will have to explicitly right click and run the app?

Finally is there any restrictions to what you can do in code on OS X when you don't sign the app or go through the app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** be a member of the Mac Developer program, no, you cannot sign with an iOS certificate. If you do not sign, users must explicitly right click your app under Mountain Lion, Mavericks and above, unless users set their security preferences to allow apps from anywhere, which is not recommended.

If you don't sign the app, you cannot deploy to the App Store and you cannot use MAS-specific features like iCloud or Game Center. You also cannot enforce an app sandbox.

Comment: Cheers! the Sandbox seems like a restriciton much more than benefit, why would people want to use it? You don't have to use it at all once not signed right? --- also will there ever come a day (in your opinion) where signing is required?

Comment: Sand boxing is a requirement by Apple to go to the MAS. Also, it can protect your code against writing to bad paths by a coding error (like ~/Library as opposed to /Library).

Comment: You can code sign and app but not use sand boxing, yes. Signing probably will be required some day, nowadays man in the middle attacks are too common to and too easy to execute. It may not require a $99 fee, but I really supports devs signing their applications.

Comment: "You must be a member of the Mac Developer program, no, you cannot sign with an iOS certificate."  That argument is circular because the iOS certificates are issued by nobody else but Apple, Inc, which runs Mac App store.

Comment: Yes, but they are two different kinds of certificates: one for OS X distribution, and one for iOS distribution. OS X checks the certificate and will reject an app signed with an iOS certificate. Apple does this so you can't just pay for the iOS program and yet deploy to both OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not the matter of joining the developer program.  The popup could appear unless you distribute your applications through Mac App Store.  See Security & Privacy Preference Pane in Preferences.
2. I'm sorry.  I've never heard of signing desktop applications with iOS certificates.
3. You don't have to join the developer program in order to code-sign your applications.  There are other certificate authorities.  For example, VeriSign (owned by Symantec) is one.  Unlike Apple, Inc., Microsoft does not act as a certificate authority.  So they exclusively use VeriSign to offer code certificates to their Windows Store developers.  Windows Store developers also have to join Microsoft's developer program separately.  In fact, I'm a Windows Store developer member.  Anyway, again, there are software certificate venders.  But their prices are a lot more expensive.  ($150 ~)
4. If you have purchased a code certificate, you can code-sign your applications with a terminal app (productbuild).  In fact, I used to do that for a while.
5. Why don't you join Mac App Store?  It's worth the price.  Paying $99 or equivalent, you'll get to use OS software and Xcode without a fee.  You can use Mac App Store software certificates to unofficially code-sign your applications even if you don't distribute them through Mac App Store.
6. There are no restrictions as to what you do with your desktop applications you develop.  Even if you don't want to or can't code-sign your applications, you can still distribute them.  And other people can use them.

Comment: Number 3 is incorrect. To get past Gatekeeper, you must sign with an Apple certificate. You can sign with other certificates, but the only true way to run totally scot-free on OS X is with an Apple-issued certificate.

Comment: No. 3 doesn't refer to Gatekeeper.  See No. 1.

Comment: THanks TBlue good info there, upvoted.

Comment: But he was referring to code signing to get past Gatekeeper.

Comment: Code-signing applications with Mac App Store certificates is not sufficient in order for you to get past Gatekeeper.

Comment: This confuses the effect of signing with different types of certificates. If you join the Mac dev program, you get dev ID certificates (for distributing outside the App Store, recognized by Gatekeeper), and other certs for submitting to the App Store (*not* recognized by Gatekeeper; if the App is accepted, Apple resigns it with a cert Gatekeeper will recognize). Gatekeeper will not recognize *any* other certs: iOS dev certs, third party certs (Verisign etc), etc; these may be valid for other purposes, but Gatekeeper ignores them.

Comment: Right...  As No. 1 says, unless you distribute your applications through Mac App Store, whether or not you code-sign them with certificates issued by Apple, Inc. as certificate authority, GateKeeper can kick in.

Comment: @TBlue: not quite; in default mode, Gatekeeper will allow apps signed with a developer ID cert (only available by joining the Mac dev program). For this reason, joining the Mac dev program is important to anyone planning to distribute Mac software, even if they're not planning to go through the Mac App Store.

Comment: @GordonDavisson is spot on here. More info available here: https://developer.apple.com/osx/distribution/